# Null image on firebase storage. How to save it original?

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, xamarin.android

I have tried to solve an issue on my app but I couldn't find a solution. I want the app to upload the images on `Firebase Storage` after the `post` is clicked. The problem is that when I click `post` the images are uploaded as .null and I can't add them as posts on my app here is a photo of `Firebase Storage`:

[image: Firebase Storage image]

Here is the code of PostsActivity:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.selfcial.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    
    Uri imageUri;
    String myUrl;
    StorageTask uploadTask;
    StorageReference storageReference;

    ImageView close, image_added;
    TextView post;
    EditText description;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        close = findViewById(R.id.close);
        image_added = findViewById(R.id.image_added);
        post = findViewById(R.id.postPhoto);
        description = findViewById(R.id.description);


        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("posts");

        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


        post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadImage();
            }
        });


        CropImage.activity()
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .start(PostActivity.this);

    }


    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();

        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
    }


    private void uploadImage() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Posting please wait..");
        progressDialog.show();


        if (imageUri != null) {
            StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
            + "." + getFileExtension(imageUri));

            uploadTask = fileReference.putFile(imageUri);
            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
                @Override
                public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }

                    return fileReference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        myUrl = downloadUri.toString();

                        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts");

                        String postId = reference.push().getKey();

                        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("postId", postId);
                        hashMap.put("postImage", myUrl);
                        hashMap.put("description", description.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("publisher", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                        reference.child(postId).setValue(hashMap);

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No image selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            imageUri = result.getUri();

            image_added.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something gone wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that I have to initialize Uri inside `onCreate` method but nothing changed. What should it be?

Comment: It's seem that your getFileExtension method is returning a null; use a debugger to make sure the mime type is correctly retrieved

Comment: @kylexy1357 Thank you for your response. I did it and it shows me this: file:///data/user/0/com.example.selfcial/cache/cropped4720168377540316567.jpg do you know may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been noticed that the method you are using to retrieve the file mime type doesn't work on some devices. You could try some other alternatives like using apache commonsIO lib or alternatively try this code :

```
public String getMimeType(Uri uri) {           
String mimeType = null;
if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(uri.getScheme())) {
    ContentResolver cr = getAppContext().getContentResolver();
    mimeType = cr.getType(uri);
} else {
    String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri
            .toString());
    mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
            fileExtension.toLowerCase());
}
return mimeType;
}
```

Comment: I see, as I understood I have to replace everything inside my `private String getFileExtension(Uri uri)` with everything inside your `private String getFileExtension(Uri uri)`. Right?

Comment: It shows the same issue again buddy. I tried it.

Comment: It sould actually return a file extension, not that Uri. What's the value of fileReference in the line  uploadTask = fileReference.putFile(imageUri);  ?

Comment: I see what you mean. I think it is the `imageUri`, but as it seems it has to be changed to something else. I will check it out.Thank you very much for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for anyone else who has the same issue, the solution is that I should have added a `!` into this if, like this:

```
if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
   throw task.getException();
 }
```